# html nest script within select element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to follow a simple example online in an html file and I have gotten it down to it's simplest form.

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
    <select name="s1">     
        <script> 
            for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) { 
                document.write("abc") 
            } 
        </script>    
    </select> 
</form>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
"Element script cannot be nested in an element select"
```

I have been comparing it to what work in online example but cannot see what is wrong. I looked at previous answers, they do not seem to apply.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="s1">
            <script>
                for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
                    document.write("abc")
                }
            </script>
        </select>
    </form>
   
    
</body>
</html>

Comment: Initially, I got an error that said "question can't be submitted, you have code that is not indented by 4 spaces, I manually tried to do that but I kept getting same error.....only way I seemed to be able to enter code was to add as a comment, sorry for the mess....If someone can explain to me what I am missing abut submitting code that would be very helpful to me also, thanks

Comment: I've added your code into the question. Not sure why you were getting the error, but there is a "code" button on the toolbar you can use to format the code after it is added. Can you add a link to the example you are following so we can see what you were trying to get to work? The code you have is fine

Comment: Can you also let us know exactly how you are running this (e.g. what browser etc) because as I said, the code you posts works